# Scraping a react/typescript app with scrapy (python) - Scripts don't load

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm struggling with web scraping a certain webpage ( [beachvolleyball.nrw](https://www.beachvolleyball.nrw/) ) .

In the last 2 days I used every library I could find but were never able to load the script-tags.

When using the developer-tool to select a tournament the data is getting loaded, but to no evail was i able to use this with selenium and other tools -.-

The Objects I want to scrape:[image: The torunement-objects I want to scrape]

Elements in the Dom: [image: Elements in the DOM]

I have tried so many diffrent approaches, it would not make much sense to show you one hear.
Pls just have a look at the DOM when opening the webpage, when the elements are not loaded yet and
help me load the data with Splash 3.5 or any other solution you prefer :)

Thank you very much! Until then I will keep trying :)

TLDR: I am unable to load scripts from [here](https://www.beachvolleyball.nrw/) with splash or any other solutions navigating within the DOM is NOT the problem!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page rendered by `JavaScripts` you can use selenium and wait for table to load first before fetching the values from table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.beachvolleyball.nrw/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".table-tournaments.table.table-hover")))
rows=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table-tournaments.table.table-hover>tbody>tr")
for row in range(len(rows)):
    if len(rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./th"))>0:
        print("Row numner: " + str(row))
        for th in rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./th"):
            print(th.text)
        print("====================================")
    if len(rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./td")) > 0:
        print("Row numner: " + str(row))
        for td in rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./td"):
            print(td.text)
        print("====================================")
```

**Console Output:**

```
Row numner: 0
OKTOBER 2020
====================================
Row numner: 1
03.10. Sa.

C
Hürth
30/32

====================================
Row numner: 2
03.10. Sa.

C
Münster
2/12

====================================
Row numner: 3
03.10. Sa.

S
Brühl Senioren
3/8

====================================
Row numner: 4
03.10. Sa.

S
Brühl Senioren
6/8

====================================
Row numner: 5
04.10. So.

C
Hürth
11/16

====================================
Row numner: 6
04.10. So.

C
Hürth
6/16

====================================
Row numner: 7
04.10. So.

C
Münster
16/16

====================================
Row numner: 8
10.10. Sa.

C
Münster
15/12

====================================
Row numner: 9
17.10. Sa.

C
Münster
16/16

====================================
Row numner: 10
DEZEMBER 2020
====================================
Row numner: 11
30.12. Mi.

B
Beachliga Castrop-Rauxel
41/40

====================================
Row numner: 12
31.12. Do.

B
Beachliga Castrop-Rauxel
36/35

====================================
Row numner: 13
31.12. Do.

B
Beachliga Castrop-Rauxel
29/35

====================================
```

Comment: I have used your answer and was able to reach my goal, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The table you are looking to scrape is loaded by websockets. You can inspect this with the network tab in your developer tools. This is included in your webbrowser. Usually opened by `F12` or `[CTRL] + [SHIFT] + 'C'`. Then navigate to yhe "Network" tab, here you can see the websockets and the messages being sent from the server, and to the server by your browser. I think that the easiest way to scrape this is either through [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) Or connecting to the WebSocket by using a library like [websocket-client](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)

Comment: Thank you very much, i am checking the websocket out right now, this was a great help! Have a nice Day!